# Render parts of multiple textures to backbuffer (single binding, GDI)

Tags: opengl, textures

I'm trying to render parts of more than one texture to the backbuffer under remote desktop on windows (this is, using GDI with opengl 1.1).

For simplicity sake i will use an example of two textures.
Screen Resolution : 1070x700
Max Texture Size : 1024
NPOT : NOT supported

Having this information, i create two textures with res:1024x1024 (must also be square!) and rendered the two parts of screen on these like this:

1st Tex: x:0->1023, y:0->699
2nd Tex: x:1024->1070, y:0->699

Of course, the remaining surface of every texture contains garbage but i don't care because when i copy the textures to screen i'm setting vertexCoords to contain only the "correct" data. I'm pretty sure that the creation of the textures AND the rendering on them is correct because just before trying to render them to backbuffer i export them to the hard disk as png images and they are fine (of course they contain garbage on the areas already mentioned).

Now, when i'm trying to render them back to backbuffer, i do the following:

"texs" is an array of a structure which saves for every texture created its ID and the rectangle of the screen from where pixels have been coppied to (in pixels).

For every texture created i set the following parameters:

```
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

As you can see, no REPEAT is set.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, GL->width(), 0, GL->height()); // in order to re-use my saved coordinates values which are set in pixels

glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glColor3f(1., 1., 1.);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);

for (GLuint i=0; i < texs.size(); ++i) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[i]);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    /* Bottom Left */
    glTexCoord2f(0., 0.);
    glVertex2i(texs[i].x(), texs[i].y());

    /* Top Left */
    glTexCoord2f(0., texs[i].height()/(float)1024);  // 1024 -> texture size
    glVertex2i(texs[i].x(), texs[i].y() + texs[i].height());

    /* Top Right */
    glTexCoord2f(texs[i].width()/(float)1024, texs[i].height()/(float)1024);
    glVertex2i(texs[i].x() + texs[i].width(), texs[i].y() + texs[i].height());

    /* Bottom Right */
    glTexCoord2f(texs[i].width()/(float)1024, 0.);
    glVertex2i(texs[i].x() + texs[i].width(), texs[i].y());

    glEnd()
}

/* Restore values */

/* Call swap buffers */
```

Now, the result i get is that the first texture is rendered correctly but in the region of the screen where the second texture should appear, appears again the first texture! I mean, in my example, in the rectangle (rectangles set as x1,y1,x2,y2) of screen:(0, 0, 1023, 699) i get the first texture and in the rest, which is:(1024, 0, 1069, 699) i see again the first one, as if no loop of textures has taken place!

For testing purposes, in the for-loop i bypassed the first texture and tried to render only the second using x,y coordinates of the first (of course width and height used were from the second). It rendered correctly.

Is that possible that in opengl 1.1 you can't render more than one texture? It not that i'm trying to combine them to a 3rd texture or something!

ps: I don't want to first copy the texture into another buffer because it is slow. This is what i do only for testing purposes in order to save the png.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of each step in the loop, if i first unbind the texture (i.e. call glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0) ) and then bind the new one works fine, even though documentation states that when call to bind to another texture, the previous bind is broken!

Don't know why this is happening in remote desktop. When running locally this is not needed.